Sea Level pressure on different charts that has wildly different values
I was an AG in the Navy about 40 years ago and I just picked up a personal weather station.  So not a calibrated barometer at home, I started looking at nearby stations on Weather Underground(WU), https://aviationweather.gov/gfa/#pro advanced map, METARs for close airports, and the NOAA Surface analysis.
I just figured out the observation plots on the aviationweather.  It is the altimeter setting instead of the MB like most station reports.
At some stations, the altimeter converted to MB sometimes is almost 0.7 MB different.  Why?
My next question now is why is WU off from NWS.  Of course, I trust NWS, but it seems like some of their network would have figured out how to get close.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First, 0.7 mb isn't a lot.  Using https://www.convertunits.com/from/mb/to/inches%20Hg Going from 1000 to 1000.7 mb changes the result from 29.53 in hg to 29.55... that's like 20' of difference, and probably about the limit of precision for a lot of instruments. When you say "is different", different from what?  What is the truth-source that you're comparing stations against?

Altimeter setting is reported to four significant digits (e.g., 29.92) whereas NWS provides pressure information to five significant digits (e.g., 1018.8). Therefore, essentially the difference you are seeing is roundoff error in the altimeter setting and it's quite small (as was pointed out by @Ralph J in the comments).
